# What is wrong with this pinvoke?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have this piece of code that has not been modified but all of a sudden it has stopped working... I could swear that it used to work but can't guarantee it. It throws an exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ErrorMsg(123);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FormatMessageW", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, long dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId, out IntPtr MsgBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr Arguments);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetThreadLocale();

/// <summary>
/// Gets a Locale specific windows error
/// code specified.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="errorcode">The errorcode.</param>
public static string ErrorMsg(long errorcode)
{
    try
    {
        if (errorcode == 0)
            return "No Error";
        IntPtr pMessageBuffer;
        int dwBufferLength;
        string sMsg;
        int dwFormatFlags;
        //FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
        dwFormatFlags = 0x00000100 | 0x00000200 | 0x00001000;
        dwBufferLength = FormatMessage(dwFormatFlags, IntPtr.Zero, errorcode, GetThreadLocale(), out pMessageBuffer, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (dwBufferLength == 0)
            return "An Unknown Error Has occured.";
        sMsg = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pMessageBuffer);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMessageBuffer);
        return sMsg;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "An Unknown Error Has occured.";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, I can't seem to find anything? Thanks!

Comment: Show us your native function declarations at least.

Comment: kernel32.dll is a microsoft dll. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked fine when I tested it on my machine. By the way is there any reason you wouldn't prefer the following method which is a little shorter and achieves equivalent goal:

```
static void Main()
{
    var ex = new Win32Exception(123);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Of course under the covers [`Win32Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.aspx) PInvokes into `FormatMessage` but at least it's the .NET framework that should worry about it, not us.

---

UPDATE:

Here's how the `Win32Exception.GetErrorMessage` method is implemented in .NET:

```
private static string GetErrorMessage(int error)
{
    string result = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
    int num = SafeNativeMethods.FormatMessage(12800, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, error, 0, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity + 1, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (num != 0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = stringBuilder.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            char c = stringBuilder[i - 1];
            if (c > ' ' && c != '.')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        result = stringBuilder.ToString(0, i);
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Unknown error (0x" + Convert.ToString(error, 16) + ")";
    }
    return result;
}
```

where `FormatMessage` is declared like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, HandleRef lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr arguments);
```

Comment: Your answer was the one I was afraid of.  This code has been around for years and has just stopped working.. I am on Win7 x64 VS 2010 .Net Framework 3.5 do you have any differences than me?   Thanks for the tip there I did not know that existed... :) But now I wonder what is wrong and what else in my code could possibly be affected

Comment: @Matthew Sanford, well, I am not at all specialist with PInvoke and unmanaged code so I am afraid I cannot say why your code doesn't work (I tested it on Win7 x64 VS 2010 .NET 4.0) and it worked fine. I just propose a way to simplify it in a way that it will work 100% of the time. You shouldn't be afraid of answers suggesting code improvement :-)

Comment: @Darin - Im not afraid of improvements, I am afraid that whatever is causing this to throw an Exception may cause problems in other areas of code know what I mean. I am grateful for the improvement, but I still would like to know why the exception.

Comment: @Matthew Sanford, just an idea that comes to mind: maybe you could take a look at how the Win32Exception.GetErrorMessage is implemented in the .NET framework. From what I can see the FormatMessage method signature is declared using a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Matthew Sanford, see my update about how to correctly implement this method. But assuming it is already built into .NET why not taking benefit from it?

Comment: Definatly want to take benefit from the existing, but I still need to know why it does not work when it used to work and works on your system. There is something missing.... Thanks for the Info!!! perhaps I will just stop being OCD and move on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try sMsg = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pMessageBuffer, dwBufferLength);

Comment: The exception is thrown in inside FormatMessage it never gets that far.